# Can I publish a paper based on already published dataset?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I published a dataset for an experiment on a data repository. The dataset is available online and includes all the authors' names. Can I still send a research paper to a peer-reviewed journal based on this dataset?

Comment: Short answer: you absolutely can and should do so, that is pretty much the whole point of public data repositories. Many disciplines like machine learning or forecasting rely on a few very well-known datasets. (Sometimes to an unhealthy degree, because the real world is much messier than data that everyone has been studying and commenting on for many years.)